# Is there a way to obtain a serif font in Skia?

Tags: c#, typeface, skia

Is there a way of requesting a serif typeface instead of providing the name of a specific typeface to `SKTypeface.FromFamilyName`?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't get a general serif typeface you have to specify a name like this:

```
using SkiaSharp;

SKTypeface typeface = SKTypeface.FromFamilyName("Times New Roman", SKFontStyleWeight.Normal, SKFontStyleWidth.Normal, SKFontStyleSlant.Upright);
```